# How to explictly write the default rule of gnu flex?

Tags: flex-lexer

flex manual say the following.

> By default, any text not matched by a flex scanner is copied to the output

I want to understand how to write it explictly. Is it something like this?

```
%%
. ECHO;
```

Also, how to disable the default rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default rule is:

```
.|\n    ECHO;
```

(In every start condition)

Remember that `.` in (f)lex does not match a newline.

To disable the default rule, use the declaration

```
%option nodefault
```

Once you do that, you will get a warning if your rules do not cover every eventuality. If you ignore the warning and use the generated scanner, it will stop with a fatal error if the input does not match any pattern.

Since you hardly ever want the default rule, I recommend always using the above `%option`.

If you have some default rule of your own in mind, you can place it at as the last rule in your file:

```
<*>.|\n   /* default action here */
```